# Correlation between categorical variable and binary variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, binary-data

Given a categorical ordered variable with more than two categories (e.g. education) and a binary variable (e.g. gender). Is it reasonable to use correlation as a measure of how both are related? My concern is that it would only take a handful of extreme datapoints (in terms of the categorical variable) to significantly alter the correlation value

Edit:

I have two groups, one that listens to a certain information source and one that does not. Each of these groups exhibits a certain behavior a number of times on average, between 0 and 10. I’m trying to determine whether individuals who get their information from that one source present a different behavior than the ones who don’t

Comment: Your categorical variables have an order type? Replace the categories with ranks. The given p-value for correlation in most software packages assumes that the input variables were normally-distributed. I would recommend you get your p-value from an exact test since your input variable may violate this assumption quite strongly.

Comment: Yes, they are totally ordered and the categories match the ranks. One thing I was considering is instead testing the difference of the means of the categorical variable across the groups (binary variable) which should be theoretically sound by the CLT, correct?

Comment: What is your research question, if the categorical ordered (ordinal) variables differ between the two binary groups?

Comment: Yes, is there a significant difference in the categorical variable responses between the two binary groups

Comment: "Significant" meaning what?

Comment: In the classic “p-value less than 0.05” sense

Comment: But what facet(s) of the data/distributions (e.g., median)?

Comment: Initially I was considering going for Spearman correlation as evidence for the existence of a relationship between the variables, but then I opted for the two sample t-test due to the concerns I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126729/discussion-between-dave-and-tvbc).

Comment: Spearman correlation between the {0, 1} variable and the {0, 1,…,10} variable. I did a two sample t-test on the means of the {0, 1, …,10} variable for both groups

Comment: Please go into the chat link to continue this discussion.

Comment: @tvbc Given your edit expressing that you want to know whether there is a difference in behaviour between the two groups, correlation  hypothesis test is not what you want.

Comment: @tvbc What test you should use depends on the distribution properties, which Dave asked about previously.